# Filter Boolean value in SAP UI5 model

Tags: sapui5

I have a SAP UI5 table.One of the column is giving me Boolean values

[image]

I want to use filter in this column. 
My dialog view code is:

```
            <ViewSettingsFilterItem
            text="Module Added"
            key="moduleAdded"
            multiSelect="false">
            <items>
                <ViewSettingsItem text="true" key="moduleAdded___EQ___true___X" />
                <ViewSettingsItem text="false" key="moduleAdded___EQ___false___X" />
            </items>
        </ViewSettingsFilterItem>
```

my controller code:

```
var aFilters = [];
        jQuery.each(mParams.filterItems, function (i, oItem) {
            var aSplit = oItem.getKey().split("___");
            var sPath = aSplit[0];
            var sOperator = aSplit[1];
            var sValue1 = aSplit[2];
            var sValue2 = aSplit[3];
            var oFilter = new sap.ui.model.Filter(sPath, sOperator, sValue1, sValue2);

            aFilters.push(oFilter);
        });
        oBinding.filter(aFilters);
```

this code is working fine for integer and string values but why it is not working for Boolean values?

Please Suggest,
Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you are passing a string instead of a boolean value which eventually leads to no result for boolean values.

Current values:

```
var sValue1 = aSplit[2]; // contains a string with value "true" in 1st Loop
```

You need to parse it

```
if (sValue1 === "true") {
 sValue1 = true; // now it is boolean and should work
} else { 
 sValue1 = false;
}
```

getKey(): @returns type String
https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.Item.html#getKey

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var sValue1 = aSplit[2] === "true" ? true : false;
```